# clang linking error: DSO missing

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors, linker, clang++

I tried to compile a project from my lab, the only things I changed from the original code using ccmake are:

```
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -fPIC -std=c++11
  CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -stdlib=libc++
```

The project also depends from another lib that I compiled using the same options. The compiling works well but the linking fails at some points and give us

```
 /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSsC1EOSs@@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

The code is compiling on another machine but for some reasons, we do not manage to compile on this system. We tried a lot of things without success.

Answer (score 4):

> `main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSsC1EOSs@@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'`

The `-stdlib=libc++` should be used both at link *and* at compile time. I suspect that adding it to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` will solve the problem.